# How can I change my panels to be dark like this screenshot?

Tags: themes, ambiance, mate

I've installed MATE/MintMenu on my Ubuntu 12.04LTS Installation:

[image]

I've changed the theme to Ambiance, in an attempt to make it look like this screenshot:

[image]

I can't get my panels dark like the one in that screenshot. Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may occur because MATE does not use all of the GNOME libraries so may not register somethings and therefore they are left out.

You can try install this theme:

[Ambiance and Radiance themes with norm-colored panel (GTK2 and GTK3).](http://gnome-look.org/content/show.php/Ambiance+&+Radiance+Colors+Version?content=147891)

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick. Here's the result, if you're interested:
http://i.imgur.com/FP9Zl.jpg